# product records is not showing through code

Tags: apex, visualforce

i created  detail page button on opportunity and associated VF page for this button i have opportunity and product,both objects have commit,serviceAddress..etc common custom fields.when i click detail page button in Opportunity i want to display product2 records which custom field values same as opportunity custom field values.here Opportunity(single location,Multi location) and product2(single location,Multi location) has two record types
 This is my code but my page is not displaying records

**Controller**

```
public class OpportunityMatchingProductsCtrl {
    //public opportunity op{get;set;}
    public list<product2> displayMatchingProducts{get;set;}
    //public string id=apexpages.currentPage().getparameters().get('id');   
    //apexpages.StandardController st
    public OpportunityMatchingProductsCtrl(apexpages.StandardController st){
        //op=new opportunity();
        displayMatchingProducts=new List<product2>();
    } 

    public list<product2> getProducts(id OppID){
        opportunity listOpp=[select id,name,Number_of_Ports__c,Commit__c,Service_Address__c,recordtype.name from opportunity where id =:OppID];
        list<product2> Productlist=[select id,name,Number_of_Ports__c,Commit__c,Service_Address_1__c,recordtype.name from product2];
        boolean oppSize=false;
        if(listOpp != null ){
            string recordtype='Single Location IP Transit/Internet';
            string recordtype1='Multi Location IP Transit/Internet'; 
            //boolean recShow=false;
            if(listOpp.recordtype.name==recordtype) {
                for(product2 p:Productlist){
                    if(listOpp.commit__c==p.Commit__c && listopp.Number_of_Ports__c==p.Number_of_Ports__c &&
                       listopp.Service_Address__c==p.Service_Address_1__c && p.recordtype.name=='Single Location Product'){

                           displayMatchingProducts.add(p);
                       }
                }
            }
            if(listOpp.recordtype.name==recordtype1) {
                for(product2 p:Productlist){
                    if(listOpp.commit__c==p.Commit__c && listopp.Number_of_Ports__c==p.Number_of_Ports__c &&
                       listopp.Service_Address__c==p.Service_Address_1__c && p.recordtype.name=='Single Location Product'){

                           displayMatchingProducts.add(p);
                       }
                }
            }
            else{
                ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,'Unfortunately you have not selected any corresponding  recordtype for this opportunity. Please select Either single location recordtype or multi location recordtype record then you find matching products'));
                return null;                                     
                // system.debug('No button Action done for this opportunity');
            }
        }
        try{
            if(displayMatchingProducts.size()>0){
                //return displayMatchingProducts;  
            }
        } 
        catch(exception e){
            system.debug('No opportunity is present'+e);
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR,e.getMessage()));
            return NULL; 
        }
        return displayMatchingProducts;

    }
}
```

**Page**

```
<apex:page standardController="opportunity" extensions="OpportunityMatchingProductsCtrl">

    <apex:form title="Matching products for this opportunity"> 
        <apex:pageblock >
           <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!displayMatchingProducts}" var="show"> 
               <apex:outputText value="{!show.id}"/>
               ID<apex:column value="{!show.id}"/>
               <apex:outputText value="{!show.name}"/> 
               Name<apex:column value="{!show.name}"/> 
               <apex:outputText value="{!show.Commit__c}"/>
               Commit<apex:column value="{!show.Commit__c}"/>
               <apex:outputText value="{!show.Service_Address_1__c}"/>
               Service Address<apex:column value="{!show.Service_Address_1__c}"/>   
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >

            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageMessages id="showMessage"> 
            </apex:pageMessages>
        </apex:pageblock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your getProducts() is not called anytime.
**Edit the controller:**

```
public OpportunityMatchingProductsCtrl(apexpages.StandardController st){
    //op=new opportunity();
    Id idVar = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')
    displayMatchingProducts=new List<product2>();
    displayMatchingProducts = getProducts(idVar);
}
```

Comment: Hi,i have added your suggested code but i am getting following error

Comment: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: getProducts() at line 9 column 35

Comment: you have to provide object id in your function. I've edited my answer.

Comment: sorry,i didn't understand,what object is i need to provide. could u pls send the snippet of code.   thanks:

Comment: Object : opportunity id

Comment: https://<salesforce-instance>/apex/<your custom apex page>?id='<opportunity id>'

Comment: this is working fine for single location record type,not working multi location

Comment: Under **if(listOpp.recordtype.name==recordtype1)** you might want to change  **p.recordtype.name=='Single Location Product'** to **p.recordtype.name=='Multi Location Product'**

Comment: when i click button on single location detail page else statements are displaying,for multi selction it is displaying blank page,why that first if and second if is not excecuting

Comment: i replaced with single Location Product with  Multi Location Product  in second if loop

Comment: check your RecordType name for lower case/ upper case / or any spelling mistakes.